# Configure Apache Jena RDF reasoner

Tags: sparql, jena

I am trying to setup a reasoner for Apache Jena.
But I cannot get it working.

When I have a `skos` concept with `skos:broader`, I cannot query that concept by searching in the result by `skos:narrower`

Currently my `config.ttl` looks like see below.
Do I need to load the schema for `skos` in the configuration to make this work?

```
## Licensed under the terms of http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

## ---------------------------------------------------------------
## Service with only SPARQL query on an inference model.
## Inference model base data is in TDB.

<#service2>  rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label               "skos" ;
    fuseki:name              "skos" ;             
    fuseki:serviceQuery      "sparql" ;          # SPARQL query service
    fuseki:serviceUpdate     "update" ;
    fuseki:dataset           <#dataset> ;
    .

<#dataset> rdf:type       ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph       <#model_inf> ;
     .

<#model_inf> a ja:InfModel ;
     ja:baseModel <#tdbGraph> ;
     ja:reasoner [
         ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/RDFSExptRuleReasoner>
     ] .

## Base data in TDB.
<#tdbDataset> rdf:type tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "run/databases/skos" ;
    # If the unionDefaultGraph is used, then the "update" service should be removed.
    # tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ;
    .

<#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
    tdb:dataset <#tdbDataset> .
```

My data would look something like this.
I would expect the `example.com/1` to have `example.com/2` as `narrower` as it is the inverse of `broader`.

```
<http://example.com/2>
    a                 skos:Concept ;        
    skos:broader      <http://example.com/1> ;        
    skos:prefLabel    "schaapskooi"@nl .

<http://example.com/1>
    a                  skos:Concept ;                
    skos:prefLabel     "restant landschapstermen"@nl ;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input and the conclusion you'd expect? It's not clear to me whether the skos stuff would work with rdfs /owl reasoning, or if you'd need custom rules.  I kind of recall skos having a custom semantics...

Comment: Sure I have added a sample of data, would I need to load the skos rdf perhaps somewhere? http://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.rdf